# divisor problem $\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{2 x}{k}-\frac{\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi n x}{k}\right)}{\pi n}\right)$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

working in the divisor problem a get a sum very relationate about the problem but i do not to continue any idea how resolve it 
$$\sum _{k=1}^{\infty } \left(\frac{2 x}{k}-\frac{\sin \left(\frac{2 \pi  n x}{k}\right)}{\pi  n}\right)$$

Comment: I assume you want the closed form and not an approximation?

Comment: yes if it is possible